# Android. Strange activities behaviour. Activities dependency within application

Tags: android, android-activity

I am experiencing a strange behavior. In my application I have activity "A" which runs Service "S". The main responsibility of "S" is to set a new `AlarmManager` for specific time. There is also receiver "R" to receive an `AlarmManager` trigger event. The Receiver sends a broadcast message to "S", which will in some cases start a new activity "B" using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

The problem is that if "A" is on or was moved to the background (by using `moveTaskToBack()`) everything works just fine. However, if activity "A" was destroyed, "B" would never appear on the screen.
Why is this happening and what is the possible solution? I think using `moveTaskBack()` is not the best way.

How does "B" depend on the existence of "A"?

Comment: How are you creating your service from A?

Comment: Creating a new Intent                                             intent = new Intent(this, SomeService.class);
startService(intent);

Comment: Can you show us your "R"?

Comment: `public class SomeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {   Intent informSomeService = new Intent(“test”);
informSomeService.putExtra(“testCommand”, 7777);
context.sendBroadcast(informSomeService);` I know for sure that receiver works just fine and service gets a message, I can see it in the log and Toast which I attached. Activity B is just not been called, and if I run Activity "A" again everything start working fine again.